# Ordering with Union Freetext and Contains

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, full-text-search, union

I want to make a search with CONTAINS operator (to select rows that match exactly) and also search with FREETEXT to match separate words in the search phrase.

The primary goal is to **order** the **results** in a way that **exact matches are first**.

Here is the sample of code I tried but the results get **doubled**:

```
SELECT TOP 100
       TreeID AS ObjectID,
       PageTitle AS Title,
       SUBSTRING(PlainPageContent, 1, 256) AS [Description],
       1 AS Priority
FROM TreeTexts 
WHERE FREETEXT((PlainPageContent, MenuTitle, PageTitle, WindowTitle), @SearchWord)
  AND LanguageID = @LangID

UNION

SELECT TOP 100
       TreeID AS ObjectID,
       PageTitle AS Title,
       SUBSTRING(PlainPageContent, 1, 256) AS [Description],
       0 AS Priority
FROM TreeTexts 
WHERE CONTAINS((PlainPageContent, MenuTitle, PageTitle, WindowTitle), '"'+@SearchWord+'"')
  AND LanguageID = @LangID

ORDER BY Priority
```

This probably is not the best select command for what i need, so could you please lead me to the right way.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can remove duplicates from the result. It is going to be a long query, but here I have given it a shot:

```
Delete  T1 From Table1 as T1 INNER JOIN Table1 as T2 ON 
T1.Field1=T2.Field1 And T1.ID < T2.ID
```

Other ways of doing it are:

- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/139444
- http://www.orafaq.com/faq/how_does_one_eliminate_duplicates_rows_from_a_table

Or you can select distinct fields from the result set.